# Return view when laravel job is completed?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, jobs

I have registered a queue and I want to return the view after I dispatch the job. The logic of what I am trying to achieve is:

1. Click on button (method brings you to controller)
2. dispatch job
3. return loading screen
4. Once the job is done, return a view with data.

This is what I have so far and the return view it isn't working.

This is my code:

```
public function demoIndex(Request $request){ //Controller

    $text = $request->input('doc');
    dispatch(new Do($text));

    return view('demo/loading');  //loading screen
}

public function handle()
{
    //queue job
   ...

    return view('demo/admin', ['search' => $search]);  //returning view (not working)
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? A queue handler can't really return a view.

Comment: You can't return a view from a job. You can either dispatch the job then have the job throw an event when its completed and listen for that event on the frontend (this would require having broadcasting set up). Or you can have the job set some sort of "completed" tag and use ajax to periodically check the status from the loading screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire events when job is done and than use laravel-echo to catch te event on te front end so the JavaScript can or load in the data or redirect to other page.

Have al ook on those links:

- [Laracasts link laravel-echo](https://laracasts.com/lessons/introducing-laravel-echo)
- [Laracasts link broadcast](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1/episodes/12)